# C# Leer nombre de Base de Datos local o remoto

Tags: c#, mysql

Necesito que me ayuden con algo que no sé por donde comenzar.

La idea es leer con C# el nombre de la base de datos (MySQL) que hay corriendo sobre el pc donde se está ejecutando, y posteriormente, las tablas que hay bajo la misma.

Esto último es fácil:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SHOW FULL TABLES FROM data_base";
```

Pero, ¿Con qué código puedo obtener el nombre de la base de datos?, es decir, si tengo base de datos con los nombres : *data_base* , *data_base1*, *data_base2*, etc... obtenerlos.

Mil gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

para ver todas las bases de datos (en las que tenés algún tipo de privilegio)

```
"SHOW DATABASES;"
```

para saber la base de datos actual

```
"SELECT DATABASE();"
```

Comment: Para ello, necesitaría previamente como bien dices privilegios , yo uso esto:
string connString = "SERVER=localhost;PORT=3306;DATABASE=data_base;UID=usuario17;PASSWORD=1234567;";

Hay forma de mostras las bases de datos solamente sabiendo el usuario y la contraseña? es decir, sin conectarme a la base de datos.. no se si me explico...

Comment: ehmm si y no, si tenes user y pass te conectas y pedis la info. si no queres conectarte y la base es local podes ver las carpetas dentro del datadir, en MySQL 5.7 windows es `"%PROGRAMDATA%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\"`, aunque  `%PROGRAMDATA%` por lo general es una carpeta oculta (`C:\ProgramData`) asi que ahí habrá que manejarse

Answer (score 0):

Tengo la misma duda, quiero hacer un form que contenga un combobox, y que en éste aparezcan los nombres de todas las bases de datos que tengo en mysql

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/345854)